# Using ReactJS with Jinja2 and Webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, reactjs, jinja2, webapp2

I am working on a project in which i am using the react js with Webapp2. I am trying to use jinja2 in react component. It compiles successfully but when i actually load the webpage. It gives error in console. Here is the handler code in which i am simply rendering the page and passing some values.

```
class Login(BaseHandler, Handler):
    def get(self):
        jinja_environment = self.jinja_environment
        template = jinja_environment.get_template("/index.html")
        self.response.out.write(template.render({'a': "aa", 'b': "bb"}))
```

I have tried following two methods for using jinja2 in React.

**Method 1:**

```
var Main = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
        {{a}} // directly use the jinja2 variable.
        <Nav/>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="columns medium-6 large-4 small-centered">
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   );
};
```

This method gives following error on console:

[image: Error Method 1]
[image: Error Method 1]

**Method 2:**
I use this method usually in Javascript and it works fine there. It do not show the value but page renders successfully.

```
var Main = (props) => {
    var a = '{{a}}';
    return (
        <div>
            {a}
            <Nav/>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="columns medium-6 large-4 small-centered">
                    {props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Here is the page view.

[image: Erro method 2]

Please help where i am doing mistake.

Comment: Is your react code inside index.html? Jinja2 will process only that file.

Comment: @aitchnyu No its in separate `.jsx` component file which i am compiling into `bundle.js` with webpack. This `bundle.js` is included in my html file. Is there any way with which i can use Jinja2 in React components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask preprocesses only the markup in the template file. It will never do included static files. So have this script in your template before the react loading script, so that your react app can access the variable x.

In views

```
import json
....
template.render({'some_details': json.dumps({'foo':'bar'})})
return render_template('login.html', some_details=json.dumps({"foo":"bar}))
```

In template

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var x = {{ some_details|safe }};
  console.log("x and x.foo", x, x.foo)
</script>
<script src="/static/react_bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using Webapp2. This is not what i am looking for. We can use Jinja2 in JavaScript with your method. Thanks

Comment: The `|safe` thing should still work with Jinja2 and Webapp2. Is there any other issue?

Comment: Actually i want to use jinja2 in React components if its possible?

Comment: JSX is just a convenient syntax for Javascript, and not a templating language. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html . Its unlikely somebody will make a Jinja2 transpiler. given that invalid virtual dom/HTML is still valid Jinja2.